# Php localhost configuration

Tags: php, apache

I need to configure this constant, that works on on-line server:

```
define("APP_DIR","/home/u138789448/public_html/");
```

to work on my localhost. The local url to local website is

```
localhost/_/
```

I set up like this but doesn't work:

```
define("APP_DIR","/_");
```

Comment: This presumably needs to be a *filesystem*-absolute path, not relative to the document root.

Comment: `die(__DIR__);` work from there.

Comment: the result is: C:\xampp\htdocs\_

Comment: There you have it then. `define('APP_DIR', 'C:/xampp/htdocs_');` I used forward `/` rather than backslash \ to avoid having to escape them. Your output does not look like the local path is actually `/_` though. If it is and you mistyped, then correct the path `define('APP_DIR', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/_');`